# When does Rails compile CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

When does Rails compile Coffeescript resources to JavaScript?  Does it happen on-demand or at startup?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CoffeeScript compiles to JavaScript on demand when a request is made to a view that includes a CoffeeScript resource.

However, you can use the following to have CoffeeScript compile to JavaScript ahead of time:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

See this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more information on the Rails asset pipeline.

From the link:

> The file extensions used on an asset determine what
>   preprocessing is applied. When a controller or a scaffold is generated
>   with the default Rails gemset, a CoffeeScript file and a SCSS file are
>   generated in place of a regular JavaScript and CSS file. The example
>   used before was a controller called “projects”, which generated an
>   app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee and an
>   app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss file.
>
> When these files are requested, they are processed by the processors
>   provided by the coffee-script and sass-rails gems and then sent back
>   to the browser as JavaScript and CSS respectively.

...

> Assets are compiled and cached on the first request after the server
>   is started. Sprockets sets a must-revalidate Cache-Control HTTP header
>   to reduce request overhead on subsequent requests — on these the
>   browser gets a 304 (Not Modified) response.
>
> If any of the files in the manifest have changed between requests, the
>   server responds with a new compiled file.

...

> Rails comes bundled with a rake task to compile the asset manifests
>   and other files in the pipeline to the disk.
>
> Compiled assets are written to the location specified in
>   config.assets.prefix. The default setting will use the public/assets
>   directory.
>
> You must use this task either during deployment or locally if you do
>   not have write access to your production filesystem.
>
> The rake task is:
>
> bundle exec rake assets:precompile

UPDATE:
For those interested in precompiling assets for development, set the RAILS_ENV variable to development first (from [here](http://dennisreimann.de/blog/precompiling-rails-assets-for-development/)):

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: This is all about production env right? What about development env?

Comment: Updated to address development environment.